# Image needs to maintain width between 50-100% and scroll if aspect ratio is greater than 1:2

Tags: css

I am using react-bootstrap and have a `<Carousel>` that I am using to display images. I'd like for them to be contained within the container, such that the entire image is visible, except for in the case that the aspect ratio is greater than 1:2 (ie really tall images), in which case you can scroll to see the rest of the image. Here is the markup for the carousel:

```
          
      <Col xs="6" className="image-carousel-container">
        <Carousel
          activeIndex={activeIndex}
          onSelect={handleSelect}
          interval={null}
          className="image-carousel"
        >
          {orderItem.imageNames.map((imageName, index) => (
            <Carousel.Item key={index}>
              <div className="image-container">
                <img
                  className="image-carousel-image"
                  src={apiEndpoint + PATH.TEMP_IMAGES + imageName}
                  alt={imageName}
                />
              </div>
            </Carousel.Item>
          ))}
        </Carousel>
        <p className="image-count-text">{`Total Images: ${orderItem.imageNames.length}`}</p>
      </Col>
```

And the CSS I have defined:

```
    .image-carousel-container {
      display: grid;
      flex-direction: column;
      margin: auto;
      min-height: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .image-carousel {
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 60vh;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .image-container {
      min-height: 60vh;
      width: auto;
      margin: auto;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
    
    .image-carousel-image {
      max-width: 100%;
      min-width: 50% !important;
      height: 60vh;
      object-fit: contain;
    }
```

So you can see I am attempting to make these "tall images" take up half the width of the container, and then scroll to see the rest of the image.

With this configuration, everything works except for the scroll. The `min-width` appears to be ignored, and the tall images are just shrunk to fit the container.

If I switch `object-fit: cover`, then the tall images take up half the width, but I have 2 issues:

1. my "wide" images expand to fill the container vertically (I want a max width of 100%).
2. the top and bottom are just truncated, there is no scroll available.

Is there a way to get the images to just fit the container and only scroll when necessary (while still taking up half the width of the container)? I have been struggling with this for a while now and none of the existing SO questions appear to address this specific case.

Comment: 2:1 is width greater than height, did you mean 1:2?

Comment: Yes, 1:2 sorry. Really I just want the min-width to be 50% of the container and the rest to scroll if the image is "taller" than that. It actually isn't a 1:2 aspect because the container isn't necessarily square.

Comment: I believe your desired result is not achievable using CSS alone; you would need to write custom Javascript.